# Enabling default behaviour link by link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am an html css design type who is not that comfortable with jquery. I have inherited a site with the link default behaviours disabled with what I can see is this code:

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var locationHref = window.location.href;
    var elementClick = $(this).attr("href");
    var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;

    $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, 1000, function() {
        window.location.hash = elementClick
    });
      return false;
```

I need to add normal links to this one page website without messing with this code (it enables parallax scrolling). Is there any way I can do this link by link?

BTW I have seen solutions on here but I must confess to not quite understanding them. Thanks.

Comment: If I've understend you could substitute the $('a') with, for example $('.myclass').click ... and add a class at the link that you want fire the above code, the other should be normal link...

Comment: Thank you, elegant and simple and ended my growing headache. The site is quite small so was no hassle to implement. Much appreciated Alex.

Comment: or flip that on its head and add a class to the items you do not want to fire then use `$('a:not(.myclass)').click`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why anyone would blanket disable ALL links on a page in this way. Unfortunate that you've inherited such code. I wasn't sure if you meant you *couldn't* touch that code, or merely didn't want to.

If the former, you have two options:

1) Unbind this click event for certain links. For example, if you had links inside a container, `#container`, or all your links had a certain class, `.class`, you could do this:

```
$('#container a').off('click');
$('a.class').off('click');
```

These links would then be free of the inherited click event handler.

The only problem with this is you unbind *all* click event handlers bound to such links. Since the inherited event isn't namespaced, this is unavoidable. A second option is to...

2) Set up a second click event handler that bypasses the default action prevention of the inherited handler by forwarding users on to the link's HREF nonetheless:

```
$('a').on('click', function() { location.href = $(this).attr('href'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

How about giving these special links a `data-donthandle="true"` attribute. Then, check for this attribute in the jQuery. If the attribute exists and is false, simply `return true;` at the beginning of the event handler.

This would save you looking through and disabling the onclick via javascript as already suggested.

```
$('a').click(function(event) {
    if($(this).attr('data-donthandle')) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
       event.preventDefault();
       //code here for handling clicks
       alert('Stopped.');

       return false;
    }
    });​
```